# ffmpeg live stream overlay issues,while any one of the stream is lost other streams are getting stuck

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, rtmp, flash-media-server

**So far we have done**

We have a video chat client which has a set of 9 video streams (users) with
h.264 codec using Adobe FMS. Now, using ffmpeg we are able to combine these
streams into one stream using the overlay (video) and amix (audio) filters.
We are able to send the single combined stream to a live streaming service.
The stream of the active speaker is shown in a bigger size using the scale
property of ffmpeg.

Code as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://localhost/live/mystream" -i "rtmp://localhost/live/mystream2 " -i "rtmp://localhost/live/mystream3 "-filter_complex"nullsrc=size=300x300 [b1];[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=100x100 [s1];[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=200x200 [s2];[2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=100x100 [s3];[b1][s1] overlay=shortest=1 [b1+s1];[b1+s1][s2] overlay=shortest=1 [b1+s2];
[b1+s2][s3] overlay=shortest=1:x=100" out.mp4
```

**Help Needed in the following 2 major issues. Any help would be appreciated.**

1. Whenever the active speaker changes, the stream of that user should be shown in a bigger
   size. is this possible to do without restarting the ffmpeg process?
2. Right now, if one of the 9 streams stops, the ffmpeg process crashes.

Comment: Samy, did you ever find a solution to this problem?